# Set two different logging levels

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using a basic logging config where all messages of level `INFO` are getting displayed to stdout, but I'm looking to set log level of `WARNING` only for the Kafka related messages, the rest can be at `INFO` level.

I'm not sure how to set two different logging levels with minimum settings.

Current configuration looks like this;

```
import logging

logging.basicConfig(format='[%(asctime)s] [%(levelname)s] - %(message)s', level=logging.INFO)

...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `logger` object and create multiple loggers as below

```
import logging

logging.basicConfig(filename="newfile.log",
                    format='[%(asctime)s] [%(levelname)s] - %(message)s',
                    filemode='w')

# Creating an object
logger1 = logging.getLogger("logger1")
logger2 = logging.getLogger("logger2")
 
# Setting the threshold of logger
logger1.setLevel(logging.INFO)
logger2.setLevel(logging.WARNING)

logger1.debug("THis is logger1 Debug")
logger1.info("THis is logger1 INFO")
logger2.debug("THis is logger2 Debug")
logger2.info("THis is logger2 INFO")
logger2.warning("THis is logger2 warning")
```

Output

```
INFO:logger1:THis is logger1 INFO
WARNING:logger2:THis is logger2 warning
```